# Unable to connect with database with manual settings in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to connect with multiple databases at runtime so i am setting the connection properties at runtime  but i got a error.

**This is my controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;


use App\Http\Requests;
use App\central_db;
use App\barcodedb;

class check_subsController extends Controller
{
    public function fetch(Request $request){



        if($db=\App\central_db::select(['db_name', 'first_name', 'last_name'])->where('device_srno','=',$request->srno)->get()){

            foreach ($db as $record) {
                Config::set('database.connections.wesearch_barcodedb.username', $record ->db_name);
                Config::set('database.connections.wesearch_barcodedb.password', $record ->last_name);
                Config::set('database.connections.wesearch_barcodedb.database', $record ->first_name);

            }

            if($users=\App\barcodedb::where('park','=','1')->get()){

                return $users;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**And this is my model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class barcodedb extends Model
{
    protected $connection ='wesearch_barcodedb';
    protected $table = 'user';
}
```

**but i got a following error:**
"FatalThrowableError in check_subsController.php line 24:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Config' not found"

Comment: Pretty sure your error explains the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the Config facade namespace.

```
use Config;
```